# Is the Photography StackExchange specifically for physical shoots or is it also for CGIs?

Tags: discussion

If I am in the wrong site to ask this question please move this question to the correct site. Basically, I want to know if this photography site is specific to physical shoots with a camera or if I could post cgi related questions here too. I do a little of both, so it would be nice if this site supported both.

The reason I ask is because it appears that there are some questions slightly related to CGI, although it is mostly for manipulation on pre-existing images, but as for cgi by itself, I do not see anything specific to it and would like to make sure it is not off topic to this site.

Comment: Some other stack exchange sites that might take such questions include [Computer Graphics](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com) (mostly for programming), [Video & Audio Production](http://video.stackexchange.com), [Blender Users](http://blender.stackexchange.com) (specific to using the Blender application), [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com).

Comment: But if the question is for example about composition you could ask, probably the original image should be a photorealistic render.

Comment: CGI related questions are off topic. For example there is a Blender site: http://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to know if this photography site is specific to physical shoots with a camera or if I could post cgi related questions here too.

Photography and computer generated imagery are pretty different endeavors. There might be some overlap where a question about photography might also be relevant to computer graphics, but I'd say that computer graphics questions in general would be off topic here.

Examples of CG-related topics that would make sense here include:

- Using computer graphics tools or techniques to enhance photographs in some way.
- Discussion of how cameras work to enable you to better simulate some aspect of photography, like bokeh or lens flare.

Answer (score 4):

To a first approximation, photographs not CGI. Questions that are framed to be independent of CGI *might* be good questions where the issues and technology are the same as those for photography. Proposed heuristics:

1. A question that looks like a photography question is more likely to be ok.
2. A question where the answers are different due to differences between photography and CGI probably is not ok.

To put it another way, if all the references to CGI can be removed without affecting the technical answers, then there's no difference and such questions can be edited to remove CGI references.

Answer (score 0):

There are some other sites that support CGI stuff.  Blender supports anything done with Blender.  Video Production can handle CGI and animation within the scope of video.  I think graphic design may handle some CGI in relation to still imagery.